# If string was too long then CONCAT() runs

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I cut the string using `SUBSTR()` and add three dots to the end of string using  `CONCAT()` in MySQL. Here is my code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(col, 1, 4), ' ...') AS new_col FROM table
```

My problem is, the above code will all `...` after all results. In the event that I want to do that **only** for the words that are more than 4 characters. Suppose this is my table:

```
// table
+----+-----------+
| id |    col    |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | yellow    |
| 2  | blue      |
| 3  | green     |
| 4  | red       |
| 5  | grey      |
| 6  | brown     |
+----+-----------+
```

I want this **output:**

```
+-----------+
| yell ...  |
| blue      |
| gree ...  |
| red       |
| grey      |
| brow ...  |
+-----------+
```

How can I do that in MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/983e3/2

```
SELECT id,
CONCAT(SUBSTR(col, 1, 4), IF(LENGTH(col)>4,' ...','')) AS new_col 
FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(col) > 4 THEN CONCAT(LEFT(col, 4), ' ...')
       ELSE col
  END AS new_col 
FROM table
```

Comment: you could add a space, the dots, do left 4

Comment: @Drew There is space `' ...'`

Comment: i know, i mean it would avoid the case when

Comment: @Drew but for `grey` I would get `grey ...`

Comment: with left 4 you would ?